# Python tic tac toe minmax algorithm not optimizing at all?

Tags: python, pygame, minmax

I have been working on this tic-tac-toe min max project for the past couple days. Right now the program runs but the computer opponent is just choosing the first available space in number order instead of actually optimizing. Would reccomend compiling yourself to better see the issue. If anyone knows what in my script is causing this that would be super helpful.

```
# MODULES
import pygame, sys
import numpy as np

# initializes pygame
pygame.init()

# ---------
# CONSTANTS
# ---------
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600
LINE_WIDTH = 15
WIN_LINE_WIDTH = 15
BOARD_ROWS = 3
BOARD_COLS = 3
SQUARE_SIZE = 200
CIRCLE_RADIUS = 60
CIRCLE_WIDTH = 15
CROSS_WIDTH = 25
SPACE = 55
# rgb: red green blue
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BG_COLOR = (28, 170, 156)
LINE_COLOR = (23, 145, 135)
CIRCLE_COLOR = (239, 231, 200)
CROSS_COLOR = (66, 66, 66)

# ------
# SCREEN
# ------
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (WIDTH, HEIGHT) )
pygame.display.set_caption( 'TIC TAC TOE' )
screen.fill( BG_COLOR )

# -------------
# CONSOLE BOARD
# -------------
board = np.zeros( (BOARD_ROWS, BOARD_COLS) )

# ---------
# FUNCTIONS
# ---------
def draw_lines():
    # 1 horizontal
    pygame.draw.line( screen, LINE_COLOR, (0, SQUARE_SIZE), (WIDTH, SQUARE_SIZE), LINE_WIDTH )
    # 2 horizontal
    pygame.draw.line( screen, LINE_COLOR, (0, 2 * SQUARE_SIZE), (WIDTH, 2 * SQUARE_SIZE), LINE_WIDTH )

    # 1 vertical
    pygame.draw.line( screen, LINE_COLOR, (SQUARE_SIZE, 0), (SQUARE_SIZE, HEIGHT), LINE_WIDTH )
    # 2 vertical
    pygame.draw.line( screen, LINE_COLOR, (2 * SQUARE_SIZE, 0), (2 * SQUARE_SIZE, HEIGHT), LINE_WIDTH )

def draw_figures():
    for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
        for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
            if board[row][col] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle( screen, CIRCLE_COLOR, (int( col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE//2 ), int( row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE//2 )), CIRCLE_RADIUS, CIRCLE_WIDTH )
            elif board[row][col] == 2:
                pygame.draw.line( screen, CROSS_COLOR, (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SPACE, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE - SPACE), (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE - SPACE, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SPACE), CROSS_WIDTH )    
                pygame.draw.line( screen, CROSS_COLOR, (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SPACE, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SPACE), (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE - SPACE, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE - SPACE), CROSS_WIDTH )

def mark_square(row, col, player):
    board[row][col] = player

def available_square(row, col):
    return board[row][col] == 0

def is_board_full():
    for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
        for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
            if board[row][col] == 0:
                return False

    return True

def is_board_empty(b):
    for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
        for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
            if b[row][col] == 0:
                return True

    return False

def check_win(player, b):
    # vertical win check
    for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
        if b[0][col] == player and b[1][col] == player and b[2][col] == player:
            #draw_vertical_winning_line(col, player)
            return True

    # horizontal win check
    for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
        if b[row][0] == player and b[row][1] == player and b[row][2] == player:
            #draw_horizontal_winning_line(row, player)
            return True

    # asc diagonal win check
    if b[2][0] == player and b[1][1] == player and b[0][2] == player:
        #draw_asc_diagonal(player)
        return True

    # desc diagonal win chek
    if b[0][0] == player and b[1][1] == player and b[2][2] == player:
        #draw_desc_diagonal(player)
        return True

    return False


def restart():
    screen.fill( BG_COLOR )
    draw_lines()
    for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
        for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
            board[row][col] = 0

def minimax(b, max_play, play):
    if play == 1 and check_win(play, b):
        return -1
    if play == 2 and check_win(play, b):
        return 1
    if is_board_empty(b) == False:
        return 0
    if max_play:
        best = -10000
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                if b[row][col] == 0:
                    b[row][col] = 2
                    best = max(best, minimax(b, False, play))
                    b[row][col] = 0
        return best
    else:
        best = 10000
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                if b[row][col] == 0:
                    b[row][col] = 1
                    best = min(best, minimax(b, True, play))
                    b[row][col] = 0
        return best

def best_move(b, play):
    best = -1000
    move = (-1, -1)
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if b[row][col] == 0:
                b[row][col] = 2
                move_val = minimax(b, False, 2)
                b[row][col] = 0

                if(move_val > best):
                    move = (row, col)
                    best = move_val
    return move

def cpu_turn(b, play):
    choice = best_move(b, play)
    b[choice[0]][choice[1]] = 2


draw_lines()    

# ---------
# VARIABLES
# ---------
player = 1
game_over = False

# --------
# MAINLOOP
# --------
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over and player == 1:

            mouseX = event.pos[0] # x
            mouseY = event.pos[1] # y

            clicked_row = int(mouseY // SQUARE_SIZE)
            clicked_col = int(mouseX // SQUARE_SIZE)

            if available_square( clicked_row, clicked_col ):

                mark_square( clicked_row, clicked_col, player )
                if check_win( player, board ):
                    game_over = True
                draw_figures()
                player = player % 2 + 1

                

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                restart()
                player = 1
                game_over = False
    if player == 2 and not game_over:
        cpu_turn(board, player)
        if check_win( player, board ):
            game_over = True
        draw_figures()
        player = player % 2 + 1

        

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Just eyeballing your minimax function, it seems like it should be making a copy of the board at some point, but it's not.  Maybe you could try adding some `print`s to help you visualize what each iteration is testing -- if it's working correctly, you should see each call to minimax play out the entire game to its conclusion in each possible way.

Comment: A couple issues at a glance:
- your minimax function does not alternate the player (it switches between maximizing and minimizing, but "play" is not updated), your win condition seems to rely on it
- in general the code seems a bit messy and redundant, I'd suggest cleaning up a bit. For example, it looks like play and max_play should be the same thing.